# Partition collection of documents using sets of words

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I have a set of documents `D`, that I need to partition into `K` pseudo equal partitions. Each partition `d_k` is defined in terms of a set of words `W_d_k`. In other words, `d_k` is the union of all documents that contain any word in `W_d_k`.

Is there an algorithm that would help me define the `K` sets of words in order to build the `K` partitions?

Note 1: I know that this problem is not necessarily solvable. But I'm trying to do as best as possible.

Note 2: I define the performance this way: Maximize the ratio of coverage `D'/card(D)`, such that `D'=Sum_k[Min(card(d_k),card(D)/k)]`

Note 3: Each partition `d_k` *must* be of a maximum size of `card(D)/K`.

Note 4: It is permissible to have a document belonging to more than one set, but this means that I will loose some coverage because of the conditions mentioned in notes 2 and 3.

Comment: Do you really mean a partition, i.e. disjoint sets? At any rate, whether the problem is solvable depends on the texts and `K`. Also, I doubt you want to define D' the way you did; Min(size(d_k),size(D)) = size(d_k) since d_k is a subset of D - I assume that by the size of a set, you mean its cardinality.

Comment: I've added some clarification notes.

Comment: This might be related to vertex cover: add a vertex per text `t` and a vertex per word `w` occurring in any text. Add an edge between vertices `w` and `t` if word `w` occurs in text `t`. Now you want to cover as many vertices representing texts as possible with a bunch of restrictions. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Sounds like a nice representation!

Comment: One thing you can immediately do is throw away all vertices for words `w` where `deg(w) > card(D)/K` since you can't put those into any `W_d_k` without violating `3`. Maybe that's a bit too obvious to put here, though.